# $ sign Significance in R while using dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

what is the significance of $ sign in R? Especially if i want to change a missing value in dataframe from NA to some value?
ex-
We have two vectors v1 and v2. We created a dataframe- mydf. v1 <- c("JACK","JOHN","JACK","JOHN") and v2 <- c(10,20,NA,NA).Now if i want to replace the missing value for JACK as 20 in variable v2. what will be the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use `$` to replace values in a data.frame object:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c("JACK","JOHN","JACK","JOHN"),
  v2 = c(10,20,NA,NA)
)

df$v2[df$v1 == "JACK"] <- 20
df
# v1 v2
# 1 JACK 20
# 2 JOHN 20
# 3 JACK 20
# 4 JOHN NA
```

Using the is.na() function to create a logical vector for subsetting:

```
df$v2[is.na(df$v2)] <- 99
df
# v1 v2
# 1 JACK 20
# 2 JOHN 20
# 3 JACK 20
# 4 JOHN 99
```

Comment: and can i do same program using is.na()?

Comment: Here is one last doubt.  mydf[mydf$v1==_________ & is.na(_____) <- 20. What will be the fill up value?

Comment: Perhaps this `mydf$v2[mydf$v1 == "Jack" & is.na(mydf$v2)] <- 20`?